# AutoComplete foreach with 0

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to generate a row with some numbers like ", 0, 5, 21, 68, 2" (I will use them for some stats). Anyway, I get the numbers from a MySQL database and I process them with a foreach like this:

```
$stats= '';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $stats.= ', '.$row['total'];
}
```

The problem if that sometimes I don't have 5 rows, I have only 3 for example. What can I do to auto complete foreach with 0, 'till five numbers are generated, something like ", 0, 5, 21, 0, 0"? I have no ideea how to do that. Thank you!

Comment: create a loop to 5, check how many results are returned from your query, fill in the rest > result with whatever number you want. In order words, if ($i < $numresult) fill $stats with the $row otherwise fill with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through and add remaining zeros into array, and use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with delimiter `,` to get desired result.

```
$stats = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $stats[] = $row['total'];
}

$count = count($stats);
for($i=$count; $i <= 5; $i++){
  $stats[] = 0;
}
echo implode(',', $stats);
```

Comment: You could also pre fill the $stats array with `$stats = array_fill(0, 5, 0);`